# Java FX 2 on IBM jdk?

Tags: javafx, java-7, ibm-jdk

Does IBM's java 7 bundle Java FX 2? I have JDK Version 7 Release 1 for Linux (32 bit) and it doesn't seem to contain it. If it doesn't, can I still use it, and what do I need to do for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

No, IBM Java 7 does not include JavaFX 2.

The Oracle distributions of Java 7 and 8 are the only supported Java runtimes that include JavaFX that I am aware of at this time.

JavaFX 2 is mostly closed source, so you can't really port it to any other runtimes.

JavaFX 8 is completely open source, so you should be able to port it to other runtime environments.  Normally JavaFX 8 requires Java 8, but there is a [Java 7 compatible back port of JavaFX 8](https://bitbucket.org/narya/jfx78) which you could (try to) run on IBM Java 7.  If you want JavaFX 8 to work on an IBM JDK, it would probably be easiest to try [building JavaFX 8](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Building+OpenJFX) against the [IBM JDK 8 beta](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/beta/) and seeing if that works.  I'm sure IBM would thank you if you are able to make it work and let them know how you did it.